# How To Prevent $variables In Restangular Post Request

Tags: c#, typescript, restangular

**Typescript:**

```
interface IFoo {
    description: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

interface Foo extends IFoo {
    $myId: string;
    $type: string;
}
```

**Restangular Call:**

```
public myFoo: Foo;    
//after setting the value of this.myFoo
this.restangular.all("api/foo").post(this.myFoo);
```

**Server Side (.net):**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Controller
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Foo foo)
{
    var updatedFoo = this._fooService.SaveFoo(foo);
    return this.Ok(updatedFoo);
}
```

**QUESTION:**

My variable (this.foo) in the typescript restangular call contains all the information needed. But inside the controller the variable "foo" is undefined or null. I tried changing the type of "this.myFoo" in my typescript to interface "IFoo" and it works. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think previously this is not a problem with restangular as they don't include other variables with $ symbol in the post request. I recently updated my restangular so maybe this is one of the cause? Is this configurable?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is inconsistent. Is it `myFoo` or `foo`?

```
public myFoo: Foo;    
//after setting the value of this.myFoo
this.restangular.all("api/foo").post(this.foo);
```

Most likely an issue with the wrong `this` though. More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: sorry mate, I've corrected it already :)
I think it is restangular-related issue. The value of "this.myFoo" in the restangular call is correct but wrong in the controller part.